# TYPO3 Composer mode PSR-4 not loading classes

Tags: php, typo3, psr-4

I have an extension located under `ext/my_ext`. My viewhelper is located under `/ext/my_agarar_template/Classes/ViewHelpers/TestViewHelper.php`.

when I try to call my viewhelper, my template says that my class doesn't exist.

My template looks like this:

```
{namespace p=ext\my_ext\ViewHelpers}
h1>ViewHelper-Test</h1>
<p><p:HelloWorld /></p>
```

Here is my error message:

> Oops, an error occurred! Fluid parse error in template
>   Standard_action_my_ext_slide_db2750e6ca45c0832d4fc312cf0618afbe9329d0,
>   line 11 at character 5. Error: The ViewHelper "" could
>   not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the
>   class "ext\my_ext\ViewHelpers\TestViewHelper", however this class does
>   not exist. (error code 1407060572). Template source chunk:
>    More information regarding this error might be
>   available online.

I load it via Composer and my PSR-4 looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "myext\\MyExt\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Classes"
    }
}
```

I don't know why my classes aren't loading.

Hope someone can help me,

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post your template where you are trying to use the viewhelper. Also you should post the exact error message you see.

Comment: Your psr-4 declaration is wrong, this should be "myext\\MyExt\\": "Classes". After the change you have to run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, your autoload section looks weird in composer.json. However, your autoloading seems to be working, otherwise you would probably not get this far, I guess.

I would check the following:

- check composer.json autoload section
- check spelling of files and class names: The ViewHelper class should be in Classes/ViewHelpers and should be the same filename + classname HelloWorldViewHelper.php and class HelloWorldViewHelper (this looks ok from your sample code)
- is namespace correct in ViewHelper class?
- just to be sure: Is your template code valid XML? (there is a '<' missing in h1)
- why is the class called TestViewHelper but the name is HelloWorld? Should be HelloWorldViewHelper and `<p:helloWorld>`. Watch for upper / lower case.
- clear entire cache (again) and dump autoload (again) `composer dump-autoload`
- you can check the file vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php to see if the mapping namespace to filename is correct.

In general, I would stay away from extension keys with underscores ('_'). This is also [recommended in the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/NamingConventions/Index.html). The thing is: The spelling, using correct upper and lowercase, vendor name or not etc. can be challenging enough. Using underscore in extension keys makes this even more difficult. Not a problem if you know the rules or know where to look but poses unnecessary difficulties for beginners.

Tip: Look in [bootstrap_package](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package). It has an underscore in the name and contains ViewHelpers.